# Getting error :(The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized) when trying to call http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm following [this Url](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) to authenticate user to my website using twitter login. I'm able to get the access token but when im calling below code

```
 url = "http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json";
            xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
```

im getting 401 unauthorized error. Can anyone guide me what can be the problem

Comment: try this https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1750

Comment: @sajanyamaha: Im not able to understand it

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the Twitter API's but here is a post in the dev.twitter forums that seem to be very similar to what you are experiencing.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1750

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. It is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json (or https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json depending of the version of the Twitter API (1 or 1.1) you use). Twitter recently removed endpoints whose domain name is not api.twitter.com and endpoints without the version of the API : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803

If it is still wrong, ensure that you authorize your requests correctly : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

NB : Twitter will send you back JSON datas, not XML. You should write "`json = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);`" instead of "`xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);`" in your code. If you want XML datas, use this URL : https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml. But this last will not work after March 2013.